# Struts2 setting object from jsp

Tags: struts2

I have queried DB and set that object in Action class and set that back to jsp to display results. Now I want the same object into another or same action class. How do I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haev also faced same issue and implemeted in the following manner. find if it is useful.

You have use conversion technique to speficy what type of Object are you going to store in the list. Then i have set it in hidden feild in jsp. then i am able to retrive it in action class.

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/type-conversion.html